# Cannot convert UnityEngine.Gameobject to String , How to phrase this script so this error does not appear?

Tags: c#

This has appeared on my script , i have dealt with this issue a couple times before but the solution was a little more obvious in then, but now i cant see why this is the case.

Any help or pointers anybody can give would be a big help , thanks for your time.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
   HQModel= this.transform.FindChild(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("HighQualityModel").transform.gameObject);
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Looks a bit like you are mixing apples and pears.

Comment: im trying to find a Child model with a specific Tag , im not sure if you can have this as a Field.

Comment: What type is `HQModel`?

Comment: And also what `transform.FindChild` is an extension you have implemented right? Can you show the method stub for it?

Comment: the code is what the definition is and im going to use it like , create HQModel or Destroy or Swap mesh with hq ect.

Comment: I can't help you with the current information you have given, but my guess would be that either `FindChild` takes a string as an argument or that `HQModel` is declared as a `string` judging by your error message. If you would like more guidance please share your declarations of `FindChild` and `HQModel`.

Comment: Find child is just a function within transform , and HQModel is just a private GameObject , thanks for your help.

Comment: `FindChild` is an extension right? I can't seem to find it in the docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Comment: yes its just gameobject/this.transform.FindChild

Comment: `FindChild(what arguments goes here?)`

Comment: (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag is what i have.

Comment: Yes, that's what you are passing it, but is it declared like `FindChild(GameObject[] objects)`?

Comment: FindChild(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Name").What you want to retrive)

Comment: If you mouseover `FindChild` you should see what it's declared like...

Comment: FindChild (string name)

Comment: `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("HighQualityModel").transform.gameObject` should probably be replaced with `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("HighQualityModel").transform.gameObject.name` since you are currently passing a gameobject and you want to pass it's name instead :)

Comment: Yes this did work  , i have used HQModel = this.gameObject  and  HQMesh = HQModel.transform.FindChild(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("HighQualityModel").transform.gameObject.name); in the if(bool)